# Best Method to Combine Gedcom files?

Tags: sql, parsing, merge, gedcom

I have collected numerous GEDCOM files (50-60) from various family members and others. I'm now retired and now want to merge/extract these files into one entity. There are obviously duplicates, some with more information than others. I am trying to decide what methods to use. I've thought of trying a GEDCOM to SQL parser, but defining the schema and all of the tables and dependencies seems overwhelming. I've also tried using manual duplicate/view/edit functions in some of the available genealogy apps, but that seems tedious and non-productive.

Has anyone faced this same situation? And how did you go about solving it?

Comment: Yes, I faced this same situation. I like a challenge and created my own GEDCOM merge app. It's easier to import, prepare and merge the family trees in a genealogy app.

Comment: See [How to merge Gedcom files?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/4091/how-to-merge-gedcom-files)

Comment: Is your app available for use by others?

Comment: Sorry, no, it does (kind of) work with my GEDCOM files but I don't think it will work with other files.